# GetPackageName including Class name of Context

Tags: android

This is how I get Package name `context.getPackageName();`.

This is how I get Class name `context.getClass().getSimpleName());`.

Then how can I get packageName including class name in one line? 
`i.e` `com.package.MainActivity`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simply leave out *Simple*:** `context.getClass().getName()`

This should work.

Alternatively if you insist on using `context.getPackageName()` and/or `context.getClass().getSimpleName()` consider `context.getPackageName() + context.getClass().getSimpleName()`.